# Is this patent granted in US or Europe or it is still in the approval process?

Tags: uspto

In reference to the patent: [EP2812386A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2812386A1)

Answer (score 0):

The EP is still in the examination procedure:
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP13716382&lng=en&tab=legal

The applicant filed amendments on 30.3.2015. There was no reply to this at the EPO yet.

I can't see a US application in the family:

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=WO&NR=2013118057A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=4&date=20130815&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&locale=en_EP